# Can I make iTunes try to identify a playlist like it would a CD?

Tags: itunes, windows

I'm slowly recovering from the [problems described in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74752/how-can-i-fix-my-music-library), and I've run across a couple situations where I know the track numbers and that a set of MP3s came from one album, but I can't figure out which album they were on. The free MP3 taggers I've found haven't done a great job of figuring out what's what.

In something of a last ditch effort, I tried burning the tracks to CD and selecting the "Get Track Names" option. Lo and behold, it worked! iTunes identified the CD as the original and helped me figure out which album I was looking at.

I have lots of these albums, and I don't want to burn a CD for each one, is there a way to get iTunes to look at a set of MP3s the same way it looks at a CD for identification purposes?

Comment: I'm commenting, as this may not be too useful, have you tried Shazam? I've used it to identify tracks/albums that had no info.

Comment: Most of the albums I've had trouble worth are somewhat oddball compilations, so I really need something that can consider the whole album at once. Looks like Shazam will come in handy once I get down to the songs which have list all their information. Thanks!

Comment: Did you import most/all of your songs from CDs?